# Magento 2 is only displaying some products on catalog page

Tags: magento2, php

I have 17 products added to my magento store all of which are enabled to display on Catalog and Search, but on the catalog page, only 10 products are being displayed and there isn't any pagination  either to display more products. When I looked at the grid.phtml which loads the products, I see these lines

```
$block->getProductCollection()->getSize()     
$block->getProductCollection()->getItems()
```

When I echo the output of the `getSize()`, I get **17** , however when I execute

```
count($block->getProductCollection()->getItems());
```

I get only **10**. I'm not sure what exactly the issue is and why there is a difference in the two outputs and what I need to do to get all the products listed. I'm using the luma theme and running magento 2.2.5.

Comment: Have you re-indexed products?

Comment: Yes, I re-indexed everything and refreshed all the caches as well

Comment: @MuraliKumar whats the value of 'Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values' in catalog system configuration on admin section ?

Comment: @shilpi singh The value is 9,15,30.  I think the reason why all the products are not displaying has something to do with loading the catalog widget on the homepage, because when I view the category page then i'm able to see all the products with pagination as well.